# MongoDB how to use the result of find to save to another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Mongoose Schema:

```
var ConnectionSchema = new Schema({
    users: [{
        social_id : String, 
        name : String, 
        hair_color : String, 
        gender : String, 
        interested_in : [String],
        current_look : {
            photo_url : String, 
            identifier: {
                type : String, 
                brand : String, 
                color : String
            }
        }
    }],
    time : {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});
```

And I am doing this:

```
mongoose.model('connection', ConnectionSchema);
var Connection = mongoose.model('connection');
var c = new Connection({
        "users": mynetwork.user_list});
```

Where `mynetwork` is the result of another `findByIdAndUpdate` call.

And when I am printing `c` I am getting this:

```
{

            "_id": "53308c83b1cd1b081df7a7c4",
            "time": "2014-03-24T19:50:27.915Z",
            "users": [
                {
                    "_id": "533073ecb3ce5208062a8668",
                    "interested_in": []
                },
                {
                    "_id": "533073ecb3ce5208062a8668",
                    "interested_in": []
                }
            ]
        }
```

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "printing `c`". Try `console.log( JSON.stringify( c, undefined, 2  ) );`. The code, "as posted" should work fine. So there is either a typing error or something with the "printing".

Comment: Originally I was saving by a `c.save(...)` and I get the same value as I put there as "printing". Currently, I use express.js response.send to see value of c in the the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a listing that works. So you probably have differences:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;

var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost');

var ConnectionSchema = new Schema({
  users: [{
    social_id: String,
    name: String,
    hair_color: String,
    interested_in: [String],
    current_look: {
      photo_url: String,
      identifier: {
        type: String,
        brand: String,
        color: String
      }
    }
  }],
  time: { type: Date, "default": Date.now }
});

var Connection = conn.model( "connection", ConnectionSchema );

conn.on('open', function() {

  var c = new Connection({
    users:[{
      "interested_in": [
        "male",
        "female"
      ],
      "current_look": {
        "photo_url": "some url"
      },
      "social_id": "Facebook:524934406",
      "gender": "male",
      "hair_color": "black",
      "name": "Faisal"
    }]
  });

  console.log(
   "Created:\n===\n\n" +
   JSON.stringify( c, undefined, 2  )
  );

  c.save(function(err,doc){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(
      "Saved:\n===\n\n" +
      JSON.stringify( doc, undefined, 2 )
    );
  });


});
```

And this will produce output like:

```
Created:
===

{
  "_id": "5330cae8c3b89719766fb529",
  "time": "2014-03-25T00:16:40.122Z",
  "users": [
    {
      "social_id": "Facebook:524934406",
      "hair_color": "black",
      "name": "Faisal",
      "_id": "5330cae8c3b89719766fb52a",
      "current_look": {
        "photo_url": "some url"
      },
      "interested_in": [
        "male",
        "female"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
Saved:
===

{
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": "5330cae8c3b89719766fb529",
  "time": "2014-03-25T00:16:40.122Z",
  "users": [
    {
      "social_id": "Facebook:524934406",
      "hair_color": "black",
      "name": "Faisal",
      "_id": "5330cae8c3b89719766fb52a",
      "current_look": {
        "photo_url": "some url"
      },
      "interested_in": [
        "male",
        "female"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Compare the code to what you have or are doing to spot the differences.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I will check this and If I was able to fix the problem, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Hey Neil, I found the problem. The object I was trying to save was the result of another findByIdAndUpdate call. Can you update your answer with this and I will accept it: "var mynetwork_obj= mynetwork.toObject(); then use, new Connection({"users": mynetwork_obj.user_list});"